# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () but visiting url directly shows image

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, picture-element

I have a weird problem where the browser says the server returns a 404 on an image.

However visiting the URL directly shows the image.  The image is within the `<picture>` element, which loads in a slightly different order.  Could that be the cause, and if so why?  Could it be cached?

Here's the site:
https://www.vamoney.squareballoon.co.uk/

And here's my code from that site:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:1201px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--1920.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width:1201px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--1920.jpg" type="image/jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:960px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--1200.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width:960px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--1200.jpg" type="image/jpg"><source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--959.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--959.jpg" type="image/jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:480px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--767.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width:480px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--767.jpg" type="image/jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:0px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--479.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source media="(min-width:0px)" srcset="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--479.jpg" type="image/jpg">
  <img src="/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--479.jpg" alt="VA Money - A picture of a calculator and some documents representing the idea that you can Borrow Money for your business requirements">
</picture>
```

The browser says the images are a 404.  But visiting one directly (it's easiest to click the one on the `img=src` shows the image.

https://www.vamoney.squareballoon.co.uk/images/aspirational-photos/borrow--va-money-main-image--479.jpg

How can it be both a 404 and also viewable?  This must be something idiotic I am doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used the `<picture>` element to show `WebP` with a `JPG` fallback.

I had misunderstood that the `JPG` would fall back, because it only falls back when the browser does not support `WebP`.  When it does support WebP it shows a 404 error if the `WebP` doesn't look.

So in this case, the issue was that the `WebP` was a 404 error but I was checking the `JPG` as I expected it to fall back.